# Making Thunderbird always show "Recipient" column in Search Messages window

Tags: thunderbird

Using Thunderbird (version 31.4.0), I want to automatically show "Recipient" as one of the columns in the Find Messages window (Ctrl+Shift+F), and have Thunderbird remember that setting after I close the Search Messages window and reopen it to do another search. I can change the columns that are displayed on the Search Messages window, but Thunderbird doesn't remember the settings.

There's a help page that describes how to set the columns in a message list and apply it to other folders: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-list-columns. However, this makes no mention of the Find Messages window.

Comment: OS which you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: It seems like the only way to save the columns you selected is by saving the search as a search folder. See [this](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/1017058) Mozilla support answer.

Comment: Why do you need to use such an outdated Thunderbird version (31.4.0)?

Comment: the question was asked 2 years back. I think OP is not updated till now?

Comment: @TechieGossip good point! I don't see then why you are nitpicking about the version number in your comment to my answer.

Comment: I am also doing R&D on that. I was using Version 38. I tried with your steps. It didn't work. So i commented to your answer

Answer (score 3):

You need an add-on for that. Easiest you can do is start with an existing add-on and edit it to suit your needs. I found the useful [attachment column in search result list](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/show-attachment-in-search/?src=cb-dl-updated) extension and just added a line to also show the Recipient column.

Here's the how-to, but I can also provide you with the finished extension if you wish.

1. Download the extension file `show_the_attachment_column_in_search_results-1.0-tb.xpi`.
2. Extract (unzip) its contents.
3. Edit the file `chrome/content/searchDialogOverlay.js` by adding the line `recipientCol: { visible: true },`:

   ```
     gFolderDisplay.setColumnStates({
       subjectCol: { visible: true },
       correspondentCol: { visible: true },
       dateCol: { visible: true },
       locationCol: { visible: true },
       recipientCol: { visible: true },
       attachmentCol:   { visible: true , ordinal: 1},
     });
   ```
4. You also need to edit the file `install.rdf` to make the add-on compatible with the latest Thunderbird version. Edit the line: `<em:maxVersion>52.0</em:maxVersion>` to: `<em:maxVersion>53.0</em:maxVersion>`.
5. Repack (zip) the files back to an archive and install it from Thunderbird's add-on manager.

**Notice:** Hacking someone else's work is nice for learning, but if I were you I'd build my own extension from scratch and publish it for everyone else to use. And I'd drop a line to the author of the original extension to thank him for his amazing work that paved the way for others.

**Considerations:** On one hand there's no good reason Thunderbird shoudn't have an option to save the preferred columns to show in the search window. On the other hand, kudos to its developers that allow easily building add-ons to extend and customize its functionality. Try and do that with a Microsoft product!

Comment: It wont work with newer version. i have tried that in my lab. Here OP requires to work in Thunderbird 31.4.0

Comment: I just successfully installed and used it on Thunderbird 52.2.1 on Windows 10. Where did you get stuck? Oh, you mean with older versions?!

Comment: i am using Version 38

Comment: @TechieGossip Just for your benefit, I installed Thunderbird 31.4.0 and the add-on does what it needs to do. Of course, you need to also edit the `minVersion` field.